how to find the rightmost data formula in a spreadsheet
Please help with the formula with the following conditions:

Look for the rightmost data in the J-O column
Then the rightmost data is subtracted from column J


Example:

In row 513, the rightmost data is in column L. So L513-J513 results 4:19:35
In row 514, the rightmost data is in column M. So M514-J514 results 8:59:45

Thank You
I've tried searching on Google, chatgpt, gemini, etc. but haven't succeeded either

Are you on google-sheet or excel?

Use XLOOKUP(). This will work both on google-sheet as well as Excel.
=XLOOKUP(0,K2:M2,K2:M2,,1,-1)-J2



Subtract From Last Numbers in Rows

=LET(data,J2:O11,
    IFNA(BYROW(DROP(data,,1),LAMBDA(r,
        INDEX(r,,XMATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(r),,-1)))),)
    -TAKE(data,,1))

